# Wamp Server put into dropbox, disable the log in the data folder

Tags: mysql, logging, wamp, dropbox

What I want to do is pretty simple. I would like to have sync for www and mysql/data folder sync.

I have successful make the change, first I point **www** folder to dropbox, and change the **my.ini**

> datadir=C:/Dropbox/web/mysql/data

(note: I know some ppls might comment, it is not good to have the mysql data sync, and try to use remote mysql database, but my problem is I do not have internet connection all the time, or my internet connection is pretty bad / slow), I just like localhost speed :)

Now my problem is, inside my C:/Dropbox/web/mysql/data there is a lot mysql-bin.0000xy file. How I can remove it, and totally disable the log in mysql.

I had tried.
login to root in mysql run

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
SET sql_log_bin=0;
SET GLOBAL expire_logs_days=10;
FLUSH LOGS; 
PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.000001'; 
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE '2011-12-31 23:59:59';
```

The log files still appear inside C:/Dropbox/web/mysql/data

Next I tried this

```
SHOW BINARY LOGS;

Error Code : 1381
You are not using binary logging
```

What I want just get rid for the log file inside my mysql data folder, so I can save the space, and dropbox do not need to sync it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://systems.takizo.com/2009/08/23/how-to-remove-mysql-binary-log/

To clean up Binary Log on Master Server

```
shell> mysql -u username -p
mysql> RESET MASTER;
```

A client that has the SUPER privilege can disable binary logging of its own statements by using a

> SET sql_log_bin = 'OFF'

statement.